# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't open Android *.xml layout files

Tags: android, xml, layout, intellij-idea

since today I'm not able to open my Android layout xml-Files in IntelliJ IDEA anymore. Other resources like styles and preferences work.

I don't mean the preview view, I only want to view the xml code of the layout files.

Thank's in advance for your help

Comment: Please try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` | `Invalidate and Restart`, check [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) for exceptions.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but it didn't work.. I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Comment: Please post the relevant exceptions from idea.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening to me as well. I couldn't open any layout XML file, but style files and AndroidManifest.xml opened correctly. I fixed this by **disabling the Android Designer plugin** in Settings/Plugins/Android Designer. Layout files are opening correctly now!

I'm hoping JetBrains will fix the root problem in a future update, but for now this workaround will suffice.

(I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6  Build #IC-129.1359 on OS X 10.9 Mavericks)

Comment: I have also this problem version 2017.1.5, no such plugin in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is that first go into the **Settings/Plugins/Android Support** and disable it and restart **intelliJ** and after restart again go into the same **Settings/Plugins/Android Support** and enable it. Your layout xml file will be open easily.

Comment: After selecting again and restarting, project lose its configurations and after setting "build target" in SDK, not opening xml files working again.

Answer (score 0):

I did delete the .android, .IntelliJIdea2017.2 and .AndroidStudio3.0 folders in C:\Users{name}\
and now I can open .xml layouts.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly  disable Android Support through Settings/Plugins/Android Support ,restart intelliJ and after restart again go into the Settings/Plugins/Android Support and enable it.If this does not work,open a new layout via Res ;That is new Android Resource file.It worked for me.

Comment: This question is over 5 years old, and already has been answered. Also, your answer doesn't actually do anything